# Error while starting zookeeper in win 10 for kafka 2.12

Tags: windows, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

While trying to start zookeeper in the windows 10 OS, I am getting the error 
\Apache was unexpected at this time

I have used the command with backlash as well as forward slash no use

E:\kafka\kafka_2.12-2.2.0\kafka_2.12-2.2.0\bin\windows>zookeeper-server-start.bat   config/zookeeper.properties

\Apache was unexpected at this

[image] time.

Comment: `kafka-server-start` wouldn't use `zookeeper.properties` anyway... Perhaps you meant to do `zookeeper-server-start`?

Comment: yes sorry zookeeper server start. path is correct I am not sure wat is that message  "\apache was unexpected at this time"

Comment: bin/windows/zookeeper-server-start.bat  is the script file that you should use for starting a local zookeeper  process.  kafka-server-start.bat  is for starting kafka process.

Comment: I have added the screen shot with the error also since this is one of its own kind of issue.

Comment: I haven't ran Kafka on windows recently, so I am unsure where your error would be coming from

Comment: always had issues under windows, I usually use the `.sh` versions with GitBash and found less problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the issue. The error was coming while setting class path as the bat file did not have administrative privilege.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `\config...` as the properties path, interpreted as **`E:\config..`** so zookeeper won't be finding its configuration properly.

I guess it defaults to looking elsewhere hence the "\Apache was unexpected at this time" error.

Just add the missing dot to the config path, i.e. `.\bin\windows\zookeeper-server-start.bat .\config\zookeeper.properties` and it should work.